# Embedding JW Player creates blank screen with Parse.com

Tags: javascript, express, parse-platform, jwplayer

I have a basic express js app set up with Parse.com.

I would like to implement JW Player so I am using their Cloud Player Library + Javascript API to embed the player.

In my /cloud/views folder I have a index.ejs file where I am trying to put the following code:

```
<script>
var playerInstance = jwplayer("zonePlayer");
  playerInstance.setup({
    file: "http://files.parsetfss.com/example-video.mp4",
    width: "100%"
  });
</script>
```

I am also using express layouts so in my layouts.ejs file I have the required Cloud Player Library file declared in the header.

Everything works fine, until I add that code mentioned above. I am then hit with a blank screen. When checking out the parse logs I see "Result: Script ran out of memory". Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, since I am using JW Player's Cloud Library JS file I couldn't add additional parameters in my  tags such as 'width'. Removing the width parameter seemed to solve this issue, perhaps because it is set on the JW Player control panel?